# Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org - Slow, Really Slow, In fact it never finished

Tags: salesforce

I was doing a deploy to Salesforce (my first) via; Right-click; "Deploy to Org" on a single file. There's no useful output to say what's going on.

`14:35:11.774 Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org`

I've read elsewhere that Salesforce can be exceptionally slow when it comes to deployment, but ten minutes (and counting) to deploy a single file seems very slow indeed. Is there a way to debug into what's happening, or is it just a black box?

Comment: Could be related to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315016/vscode-salesforce-deploy-source-to-org-very-slow-to-complete-although-actua

Answer (score 0):

Production or Sandbox? "Normal" or "source tracked" (like scratch org for example). Do you have "Output" view / tab / thing at the bottom of your VSCode where you should normally see command results (slightly different from "Terminal").

If you login to the target org and setup -> monitor deployments do you even see your attempt? If you deploy to prod by default it'll run all tests which in complex orgs may be expensive, take 1h for example.

You may get results faster if you run just 1 test related to the class you're deploying - but for that you need to whip out some script-fu.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u mytargetuser -p "force-app/main/default/classes/AccountTriggerHandler.cls" -l RunSpecifiedTests -r "AccountTriggerHandlerTest" --verbose --loglevel fatal -c
```